# Sign up form with uiwebview form in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, native

in my iOS application, I want to use `UIWebView` to create signup page which is hosted on my application server.

I have implemented it and experiment. But, i wonder, what does Apple think about getting information from user or signing up with `UIWebView`. Can my application be rejected by Apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to be fine. Apple will be fine with you allowing users to login through a website within a UIWebView within your application.